# Ionic2/Angular2 Can't Call Function within Function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, http-post, cordova-plugins

I am using Cordova Facebook Plugin to get user name/email/etc (which works fine) and then want to insert it into my own database. I have tested the posting to DB code by creating a function, tied it to a test button and that works fine too. But when I place the post-2-db code within the fb-login code, it stops executing exactly at my http-post. I do console.log(step1) and see that fine, but I never see console.log(step2) - see my code below:

```
// LOGIN TO FACEBOOK
doFbLogin(){
    let permissions = new Array();
    let nav = this.navCtrl;
    //the permissions your facebook app needs from the user
    permissions = ["public_profile"];


    Facebook.login(permissions)
    .then(function(response){
      let userId = response.authResponse.userID;
      let params = new Array();

      //Getting name and gender properties
      Facebook.api("/me?fields=name,gender,email", params)
      .then(function(user) {
        user.picture = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large";
        //now we have the users info, let's save it in the NativeStorage
        NativeStorage.setItem('user',
        {
          name: user.name,
          gender: user.gender,
          picture: user.picture,
          email: user.email,
        })
        .then(function(){
          // BEGIN INSERT USER TO DB
          // postRequest() {
            var headers = new Headers();
            headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
            let postParams = {
              userName: user.name,
              userEmail: user.email,
              userImage: user.picture,
            }

            console.log("STEP 1");

// IT WORKS UP TO THIS POINT

            this.http.post("http://example.com/post.php", postParams, options)
              .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data['_body']);
                }, error => {
                console.log(error);// Error getting the data
              });
            //}
            // END DB INSERT CODE

// I NEVER SEE THIS CONSOLE LOG BELOW

            console.log("STEP 2");



          // User Reg complete, push them to app
          nav.push(TabsPage);
        }, function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
      })
    }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });

  }
}
```

If I take out that chunk of code, everything works fine. I'm very much a beginner to coding and I'd appreciate any thorough layman-level explanation and assistance. Thank you.

Comment: You will get better answers if you strip your questions to look less like a novel and more like a very short piece of code where all unrelated lines are removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stevenvanc stated,

replace your

```
.then(function(response){
```

lines with

```
.then((response)=>{
```

otherwise your `this` will refer to that functions instance

Answer (score 2):

If you put that code into a function, your "this" changes scope.

```
this.http.post
```

"this" refers to the execution context, which you just changed and has no "http" attached. Or if you're using strict, it will even be undefined.

Try and use the new es6 arrow functions. They provide a static "this". Or simply pass the http object in.

Answer (score 1):

This suggests that your call to `http.post` causes an exception. For example, `this` or `this.http` may not be defined. Check your console window to see if you see anything related to it.

The way to catch the exception is to use try/catch block:

```
 try {
    this.http.post("http://example.com/post.php", postParams, options)
          .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data['_body']);
            }, error => {
            console.log(error);// Error getting the data
          });
   console.log("Successful call!");
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
 }
```

This should give you an insight about why the execution doesn't get pass the http.post function call.

Answer (score 0):

use `map` to get `response` from server and pass to `subscribe` block.

```
this.http.post("http://example.com/post.php", postParams, options).map((res: Response) => res.json() || {})
.subscribe( (data) => {
    console.log(data['_body']);
}, error => {
    console.log(error);// Error getting the data
});
```